# import array type into hana?

Tags: sql, arrays, hana

I am importing data into SAP HANA using the CSV files.

When I try to import a column which has an array type then it results in the following error

> ARRAY type is not compatible with PARAMETER TYPE

For example

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE"
( 'ID' INT,
  'SUBJECTS' INT ARRAY)
```

The above query creates the table and when I run

```
INSERT INTO "SCHEMA"."TABLE" VALUES (1,ARRAY(1,2,3))
```

It inserts successfully into the HANA database.

But when I try

```
INSERT INTO "SCHEMA"."TABLE" VALUES (1,"{1,2,3}")
```

It does not work.So how can I import the array values in the CSV file to the column in HANA database.

Comment: Does HANA support the Postgres style for arrays using `{...}`? And does it support using double quotes for string constants?

Comment: No SAP HANA does not support "{1,2,3..}" but instead it supports ARRAY(1,2,3...). But in the CSV which is exported from Postgres contains the values as "{1,2,3..}" only. So how could I import that CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

Array storage types can currently only be created by using the ARRAY() function.

Comment: So there is no way to import array elements into a column with a CSV file.

Comment: That's correct. You could load your data into a staging table and then transform the values into an array. But there is no "direct' way, no.

Comment: Can't we insert the array column via the INSERT method in HANA?

Comment: Only with the ARRAY() function for the columns that store the array data. What I meant was that you have to create a new insert statement for every record.

Comment: Cannot we use a loop to programatically insert the rows with a loop rather than having new insert statement for every record?

Answer (score 1):

You could construct the INSERT statement in a loop but you still need to construct the ARRAY() call for every record.

Ok, here's the example you asked for.
By now you should understand that there is no simple IMPORT command that would automatically insert arrays into a HANA table.

That leaves you with two options as I see it:

1. you write a loader program that reads your CSV file and parses
   the array data {..., ... , ...} and makes INSERT statements with
   ARRAY functions out of it. 
   or
2. You load the data in two steps:
   2.1 Load the data from the CSV as-is and put the array data into a CLOB column.
   2.2. Add the array columns to the table and run a loop that takes the CLOB data,  replaces the curly brackets with normal brackets and creates a dynamic SQL statement.

Like so:

```
create column table array_imp_demo as (

select owner_name , object_type, to_clob( '{'|| string_agg ( object_oid, ', ') || '}' )array_text
from ownership
group by owner_name, object_type);

select top 10 * from array_imp_demo;

/*
OWNER_NAME      OBJECT_TYPE ARRAY_TEXT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
SYS             TABLE       {142540, 142631, 142262, 133562, 185300, 142388, 133718, 142872, 133267, 133913, 134330, 143063, 133386, 134042, 142097, 142556, 142688, 142284, 133577, 185357, 142409, 133745, 142902, 133308, 133948, 134359, 143099, 133411, 134135, 142118, 142578, 142762, 142306, 133604, 142429, 133764, 142928, 133322, 133966, 134383, 143120, 133443, 134193, 142151, 142587, 142780, 142327, 133642, 142448, 133805, 142967, 185407, 133334, 133988, 134624, 143134, 133455, 134205, 142173, 142510, 142606, 142798, 142236, 133523, 142359, 133663, 142465, 133825, 142832, 133175, 133866, 134269, 143005, 133354, 134012, 134646, 143148, 133497, 134231, 142195, 142526, 142628, 142816, 142259, 133551, 142382, 133700, 142493, 133855, 142862, 133235, 133904, 134309, 143051, 133373, 134029, 142082, 143306, 133513, 134255, 142216, 142553, 142684, 142281, 133572, 185330, 142394, 133738, 142892, 133299, 133929, 134351, 143080, 133406, 134117, 142115, 142576, 142711, 142303, 133596, 142414, 133756, 142922, 185399, 133319, 133958, 134368, 143115,
SYSTEM          TABLE       {154821, 146065, 146057, 173960, 174000, 173983, 144132, 173970}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
_SYS_STATISTICS TABLE       {151968, 146993, 147245, 152026, 147057, 147023, 151822, 147175, 147206, 151275, 151903, 147198, 147241, 151326, 151798, 152010, 147016, 147039, 147068, 151804, 151810, 147002, 147202, 151264, 151850, 147186, 147114, 147228, 151300, 151792, 151992, 147030, 147062, 151840, 147181, 147210, 151289, 151754, 149419, 150274, 147791, 150574, 147992, 149721, 150672, 148132, 149894, 147042, 148434, 149059, 150071, 147518, 148687, 149271, 150221, 150877, 147716, 148913, 150388, 147957, 149675, 150634, 148102, 149829, 148267, 148979, 149976, 147494, 148663, 151107, 149224, 150178, 147667, 148855, 149532, 150306, 147925, 149602, 150598, 148080, 149792, 148179, 149926, 147417, 148547, 149186, 150107, 147568, 148804}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
_SYS_EPM        TABLE       {143391, 143427, 143354, 143385, 143411, 143376, 143398, 143367, 143414, 143344, 175755}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
_SYS_REPO       TABLE       {145086, 151368, 171680, 145095, 152081, 169183, 151443, 149941, 154366, 143985, 145116, 152104, 151496, 169029, 177728, 179047, 145065, 169760, 178767, 151659, 169112, 169258, 153736, 177757, 174923, 145074, 150726, 151697, 169133, 178956, 145083, 169171, 168992, 145092, 177665, 169178, 151378, 169271, 178881, 174911, 154128, 143980, 145101, 152098, 151481, 177720, 152504, 145062, 151570, 169102, 154058, 145071, 170733, 151687, 169130, 145080, 171629, 169166, 178846, 145089, 149588, 151373, 177614, 143976, 145098, 152087, 151458, 149955, 178907, 154386, 145059, 169605, 151529, 169035, 178579, 151176, 179178, 145068, 150709, 151670, 169124, 174905, 177778, 154244, 145077, 170883, 169158, 144072, 152681, 144285, 154415, 144620, 145268, 168884, 144895, 143512, 151428, 168774, 143750, 152337, 168558, 144114, 149559, 152719, 144327, 144674, 145508, 168924, 144939, 143578, 152135, 143793, 152392, 168587, 144151, 152753, 144370, 144720, 145722, 168960, 144990, 143626, 152174, 143832, 152435, 168620, 144188, 152785,
_SYS_TASK       TABLE       {146851, 146847, 146856, 146231, 146143, 146839, 146854, 146834, 146430, 146464, 146167, 146505, 146205, 146257, 146384, 146313, 146420, 146356, 146454, 146155, 146495, 146193, 146525, 146244, 146368, 146296, 146410, 146346, 146443, 146148, 146484, 146181, 146517, 146234, 146275, 146395, 146325}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
_SYS_AFL        TABLE       {177209, 176741, 176522, 177243, 176777, 176692, 176201, 177294, 176929, 177328, 176967, 177383, 177105, 177015, 176826, 177143, 177056, 176866, 177215, 176748, 176550, 176474, 177249, 176784, 176699, 176218, 146871, 177300, 176935, 177335, 176973, 177389, 177111, 177021, 176835, 177156, 177062, 176883, 185427, 177221, 176755, 176572, 176487, 177261, 176790, 176706, 176398, 177306, 176941, 177341, 176979, 177397, 177119, 177033, 176843, 177162, 177069, 176889, 177228, 176762, 176589, 177267, 176799, 176713, 176416, 177313, 176953, 177348, 176991, 177404, 177127, 177040, 176849, 177173, 177075, 176895, 177195, 176732, 176507, 177234, 176768, 177274, 176805, 176720, 176448, 177285, 176921, 177319, 176959, 177354, 176997, 177375, 177095, 177007, 176818, 177411, 177133, 177047, 176858, 177179, 177081, 176911, 177201, 176738, 176519, 177241, 176775, 176690, 176196, 177280, 176814, 176727, 176464, 177291, 176927, 177326, 176965, 177360, 177003, 177381, 177103, 177013, 176824, 177141, 177053, 176864, 177191, 177091,
_SYS_XB         TABLE       {146971, 146957}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
DEVDUDE         TABLE       {167121, 165374, 182658, 156616, 173111, 181568, 174901, 183413, 184432, 183498, 183470, 184464, 155821, 173102, 183613, 184495, 155857, 166744, 180454, 184547, 156234, 172096, 166765, 165548, 184649, 183399, 184357, 184577, 183477, 181594, 183537, 181572, 167201, 184685, 185467, 183406, 184422, 184610, 183491, 155842, 172923, 157723, 182636, 167895, 183463, 184454, 183505, 165542, 183606, 184488, 155849, 172749, 157626, 184527, 183449, 166759, 184627, 182827, 184347, 184568, 157619, 172118, 183530, 181556, 167137, 184670, 182642, 184411, 184598, 183484, 155835, 183456, 183593, 181584, 167328, 183421, 184443, 183586, 184474, 155828, 166392, 183620, 184517, 183435, 183442, 183512, 166753, 184557, 156598, 172106, 183523, 166771, 166568, 184660, 182630, 184381, 184587, 183428, 157681, 182649, 167264, 168236}                                                                                                                                                                                                                
ADMIN           TABLE       {158520, 158925, 158982, 158492, 158571, 158583, 158560, 158541, 158744}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
*/
```

Ok, let's just assume that this is the data that you managed to load from your CSV file into a table and that the ARRAY_DATA column is a big CLOB.

Now, the data is in the table, but you need to put it into an ARRAY column.

```
alter table array_imp_demo add (array_data integer array);
```

The unconvenient part follows now: creating a new UPDATE command for each record to transform the CLOB data into a proper ARRAY() function call.
Be aware that this update command works correctly, because (OWNER, OBJECT_TYPE) are used as keys in this case.

```
do begin

declare vsqlmain nvarchar (50) :='UPDATE array_imp_demo set array_data = ARRAY ';
declare vsql nvarchar(5000);


declare cursor c_upd for
    select OWNER_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE,
          replace (replace (ARRAY_TEXT, '{', '(' ), '}', ')' ) array_data
    from array_imp_demo;

    for cur_row as c_upd do

        vsql = :vsqlmain || cur_row.array_data;
        vsql = :vsql || ' WHERE owner_name = ''' || cur_row.owner_name  || '''';
        vsql = :vsql || ' AND object_type = ''' || cur_row.object_type || '''';

        exec :vsql;
    end for;

end;

select * from array_imp_demo;


OWNER_NAME      OBJECT_TYPE ARRAY_TEXT                   ARRAY_DATA             
SYS             TABLE       {142540, 142631, 142262,... 142540, 142631, 142262,...
SYSTEM          TABLE       {154821, 146065, 146057,... 154821, 146065, 146057,...
_SYS_STATISTICS TABLE       {151968, 146993, 147245,... 151968, 146993, 147245,...
_SYS_EPM        TABLE       {143391, 143427, 143354,... 143391, 143427, 143354,...
_SYS_REPO       TABLE       {145086, 151368, 171680,... 145086, 151368, 171680,...
```

After that you can drop the CLOB column.

Ok, that's about it from my side.

Comment: I could not get you exactly.Could you show a sample script  how it's been done?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CTL method to import data. I hope that might help.

Comment: I am using CTL method only but the problem is the incompatible data type.We cannot insert the array format neither as  "{1,2,3,...}" nor ARRAY(1,2,3,...)  IN THE CSV file.