# Is it possible bulk insert in HANA?

Tags: hana

I want to insert into HANA by bulk. Currently I am using Java to insert line by line from the result set. Is there a way to insert multiple rows at a time? Is it possible to do? (I do not want import only bulk insert) I searched all over and could not find any good answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific on what exactly you want to do, e.g. which language or tool you want to use. HANA does support bulk data loading - it all depends on what you want to use.

Comment: I am using java to insert data from a result set.But if I insert line by line it consumes more time.Is there a way to insert in bulk? (Insert more than one row at a time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JAVA/JDBC code, there exists the so-called batch interface.
Here's an old example that I used for testing:

```
myDBconn.setAutoCommit(false);

PreparedStatement insStmt = myDBconn
        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO EFASHION.SHOP_FACTS_INS_DEMO VALUES"
                + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?  )");

for (int i = 1; i <= LOOPCNT; i++) {
    myfacts.createNewFact();  // create a JAVA object with new data

    // prepare the new data for the batch 
    // note that this is a typed assignment. 
    insStmt.setInt(1, i);
    insStmt.setInt(2, myfacts.article_id);
    insStmt.setInt(3, myfacts.color_code);
    insStmt.setInt(4, myfacts.week_id);
    insStmt.setInt(5, myfacts.shop_id);
    insStmt.setDouble(6, myfacts.margin);
    insStmt.setDouble(7, myfacts.amount_sold);
    insStmt.setInt(8, myfacts.quantity_sold);

    // add the new data to the batch
    insStmt.addBatch();

    // limit the batch size, to  prevent client side out of memory errors.
    // but DON'T commit yet!
    // Remember the data in the current batch is kept in client
    // memory as long as we don't send it to the HANA server
    if (i % BATCHSIZE == 0) {
        // executeBatch returns the number of affected rows.
        // if we want to use this in the application we just keep adding this up
        affectedRows += insStmt.executeBatch();
    }
}
// the final batch execution for whatever remained in the
// last batch
affectedRows += insStmt.executeBatch();

// finally commit
myDBconn.commit();
```

All that is documented in the JDBC docu so it shouldn't be a problem to follow this.

Remark: ARRAY data types are not supported (neither for single prepared statements nor for batches) - just in case that is what you wanted to do...

Comment: @Lars.Br Then how to upload an array in HANA? I query and get the array in the result set but How to insert it in to HANA since `insStmt.setArray(9, myArray);` did not work where my insert satement looks llike `INSERT INTO EFASHION.SHOP_FACTS_INS_DEMO VALUES"
                + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,ARRAY(?) )");`.   But when I manually insert like `INSERT INTO EFASHION.SHOP_FACTS_INS_DEMO VALUES"
                + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,ARRAY(1,2,3) )");` works fine.

Comment: Please check the existing discussions on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102034/import-array-type-into-hana/40378906#40378906 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338263/upload-an-array-in-hana/41353326#41353326

Comment: Also: you asked for BULK data load and not for ARRAY inserts. Please be sure to use the right terminology when asking on such a specific level. Thanks.